# Way to use javascript's requestAnimationFrame correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, requestanimationframe

What is the best way to alter DOM with requestAnimationFrame when Massive DOM modifications can happen ?

The third option seems to be the best for me, right ?

First option :

```
    var a = {
        key1 : 'value1',
        key2 : 'value2',
        [...]
    };

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        if(someConditions) {
            $('elem').html(a.key1);
        }

        if(otherConditions) {
            $('elem').html(a.key2);
        }

        if([...]) {
            [...]
        }
    });
```

Second option :

```
    var a = {
        key1 : 'value1',
        key2 : 'value2',
        [...]
    };

    if(someConditions) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            $('elem').html(a.key1);
        });
    }

    if(otherConditions) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            $('elem').html(a.key2);
        });
    }
```

Third option :

```
    var a = {
        key1 : 'value1',
        key2 : 'value2',
        [...]
    };
    var stack = [];

    if(someConditions) {
        stack.push(a.key1);
    }

    if(otherConditions) {
        stack.push(a.key2);
    }

    var doTheJob = function() {
        var value = stack.shift();

        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            $('elem').html(value);

            if(stack.length) {
                doTheJob();
            }
        });
    };
```

I hope the code illustrate the situation ($('elem') is called each time but if i add code, i will not be able to post because il will looks mostly code...).

Comment: The best way is to NOT do any type of DOM manipulation at a 60 frames per second speed

Comment: So what is the best way ? buffer and limit DOM modifications ?

Comment: You don't want to modify the DOM inside `requestAnimationFrame` because DOM modifications are slow, `requestAnimationFrame` executes many times per second, your UI will freeze up, think about your logic, there is no best way here